# Count last 10 cell values if >1, exclude blank cells

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to count the last 10 cell values that are bigger than 1, in a given range, and to exclude blank cells. The formula should handle last 10 non-blank entries dynamically in a column.

I have this array formula from another forum:

> =IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(ROW(A2:A20)>=LARGE(IF(A2:A20<>"",ROW(A2:A20)),MIN(COUNT(A2:A20),10)),IF(A2:A20<>"",A2:A20))),"")

It averages the last 10 cell values, excluding blanks.

I have tried to replace the "average" function with "`countif`", and I added `">1"`, but without success,it returned zero.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Made some changes in your formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(IF(INT(IF(ROW(A2:A20)>=LARGE(IF(A2:A20<>"",ROW(A2:A20)),MIN(COUNT(A2:A20),10)),IF(A2:A20<>"",A2:A20)))>1,1,0)),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Instead of `COUNTIF` function, I am using `SUM(IF())`. For deatils see [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/275166).

Here, `INT` function converts `False` to `0` and `TRUE`to `1`.

Comment: This formula works perfectly, exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that you only need last 10 cells of your range. Assuming your range is `A2:A20`, you count the last 10 values greater than 1 as follows:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2,ROWS(A2:A20)-10,0,10,1),">1")
```

Note that you have to type in the first cell of the range (`A2`) as well as the whole range (`A2:A2O`) and you have to type number `10` twice, but that's how Excel programming is...

Comment: As per the question, OP wants `last 10 cell values in a range excluding blanks` but above formula includes blank also.

Comment: @Mrig, I fail to see how ">1" condition includes blank cells. Try it out, it counts correctly blanks or no blanks.

Comment: Point I am raising here has noting to do with `>1` condition, instead its `OFFSET` which will always give `A11:A20` in `COUNTIF`. If I understood the question correctly, if any of the cell in range `A11:A20` is blank (say two cells in this range are blank) then `COUNTIF` function should dynamically change the range (for two blanks it should be `A9:A20`).

Comment: @Mrig , Mrig point is spot on, the range should be dynamic, my question wasn't clear enough. The COUNTIF function should coun't the last 10 values in a range  a2:a20, that are ">1" , and not the values  that are ">1" in the last 10 cells in the given range.

Comment: @LorantSz, you have to modify your question to reflect what exactly are you asking. If you are asking to dynamically handle last 10 non-blank entries in a column, the simplest way to solve it would be by adding more than 1 function into your Excel sheet. Please edit your question if you want me (or anyone) to help you.